# How to return song duration in soundmanager

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

How can i return song duration in soundmanager with function ?

```
function item_duration(){
    var song_item = soundManager.createSound({
        id:'etc',
        url:'etc',
        onload: function() {
                    if(this.readyState == 'loaded' ||
                    this.readyState == 'complete' ||
                    this.readyState == 3){
                    return = this.duration;         
                    }
       }
   });

   song_item.load();

}
```

This is my try, but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` is a keyword, not a variable. `return this.duration;` is what you'd want; skip the `=` (which will just give you a syntax error)

… but that won't help much, because *where* are you returning it to? You'll need to call another function, that does something with the duration. The `item_duration` function returns immediately after calling `createSound`, which then loads the file asynchronously

Try something like this

```
function doSomethingWithTheSoundDuration(duration) {
    alert(duration); // using alert() as an example…
}

soundManager.createSound({
    id:  …,
    url: …,
    onload: function() {
        // no need to compare with anything but the number 3
        // since readyState is a number - not a string - and
        // 3 is the value for "load complete"
        if( this.readyState === 3 ) { 
            doSomethingWithTheSoundDuration(this.duration);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm going to shoot myself, axaaxaxa an equals sign, omg i don't know what to say, i know how to use return, and etc.. ogh.. no words.. so thanks, the code from you it is not good at my situation but, with the fixed damn fall mistake, it works

Comment: this is not relevant in the current version (October 2013). onload is not part of the createSound options.